# Timestamp in Java and Timestamp in my Sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, grails, groovy

I have a small problem with `Timestamp` datatypes in Grails and MySql.

I am trying to run an "insert" query in Grails to insert the date-time stamp in a table (sql DB)

```
sql.execute("insert into table_one (no, identity, user, last_updated) "
                                    + " values((select max(no)+1 from table_one),"
                                    + "'" + p.identity + "','" + p.user_id + "','" + "sysdate" + "')")
```

But it throws an error saying:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

In java Timestamp results in "**2013-10-28 15:27:20.394**" format.
In Sql Timestamp expects in "**10/28/2013 15:27:20. PM**" format.

I used `SimpleDateFormat` but it returns string, which I don't want. Even parsing the string generated to `Timestamp` returns same format.

Can anyone please share your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try converting the sysdate to mysql format before inserting.
You can try to replace your "`sysdate`" with "`str_to_date(sysdate,'%y-%m-%d')`" and give a try

Comment: I tried with: "str_to_date(sysdate,'%m/%d/%Y %l:%i:%s. %p')" but it gives error as: Message: ORA-00911: invalid character. Here is the link i am referring for writing query: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: If you are inserting in a date column then why are you considering timestamp.

Comment: Actually, I am little confused with Timestamp datatype. When I run the same query using "sysdate" on mySql editor it inserts the data Last_update (which is declared as a timestamp on DB) like "10/28/2013 15:27:20. PM" but when I use the same query on groovy n grails it throws me an error. I am trying to insert a timestamp through a groovy code but the format is not supporting. I am using Date() in groovy to get the current date-time which gives me as return as "Mon Oct 28 17:08:45 IST 2013" and converting it to timestamp using toTimestamp() functin gives me "2013-10-28 17:08:45.439"

Comment: but the timestamp returned in java n sql is so different JAVA = 2013-10-28 17:08:45.43 and SQL = 10/28/2013 17:08:45. PM . Let me know if I am missing something.